# need to return true or false based on if value in text field is a specific number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-validation-engine

I am looking to return true if the user entered 4 into the input field.

```
function validateAddition() {
  if($("#validateAddition").val() == 4) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

<input value="" 
class="validate[required,onlyNumber,length[0,1]funcCall[validateAddition]] text-input" 
type="text" id="validateAddition" name="validateAddition" />
```

Added this into the english language js file:

```
"validateAddition":{
    "nname":"validateAddition",
    "alertText":"* Your math is off, try again."}
```

This should be fine, let me know what you think is wrong.

Comment: yes I have. It ignores the value of the number.

Comment: @Brad: See my answer please and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is `validate[required,onlyNumber,length[0,1]funcCall[validateAddition]]` really a class name? Maybe your browser went on strike after trying to parse such an atrocity.

Comment: @MooGoo: From my understanding that class name is used by jQuery to perform some client side form processing. It does not exist in a stylesheet but is picked up by jQuery instead.

Comment: If that is the case then I question the sanity of the jQuery devs. If you need to stuff crap like that in your markup, you might as well go back to attaching events with HTML attributes containing eval'd Javascript strings.

Comment: @MooGoo this is the jquery "validationEngine" plugin, not some part of jquery's core. The use of class to declare the logic of validation is arguable, but that's the core idea of the plugin - someday we get our 'data' tag and we're free to do whatever we want with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

```
return (parseInt($('#validateAddition').val()) == 4)
```

EDIT: MooGoo is correct, I was mistaken as far as my explanation.

However is idea of using +val is probably not the best. While the method above WILL work as you require a much better solution would be as follows:

```
if(($('#validateAddition').val()-0) == 4)
```

The reason we want to -0 as opposed to +0 is simply because if it is a string and you want to perform any additional operations incase it is, you will no longer have the original string.

Comment: But that is *not* the reason. In Javascript, `"4" == 4 && "  4  " == 4 && "  00004   " == 4` There's no reason to manually type cast, and even then `parseInt` is probably the worst way to do it. If you must, just use `+val`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow other characters as well and return true only if the text of input field contains 4, you should do like this instead:

```
if($("#validateAddition").val().indexOf('4') != -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make sence to compare the value to a string, since the value is a string. That allows you to use strict equals avoiding unnecessary automatic conversions. Also you can simplify the function.

```
function validateAddition() {
  return $("#validateAddition").val() === "4";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your validation in the language file, looking something like this

```
"validateAddition": {
    "regex": /[0-3]|[5-9]/,//something that matches on all numbers but four
    "alertText": "* Your math is off, try again."
},
```